# Raspbian cannot upgrade packages

Tags: python, debian, raspbian

Since a few days, every time I try to upgrade packages `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following error:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales python-samba

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 33, in <module>
    from ALChacks import *
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALChacks.py", line 25, in <module>
    import gettext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 261
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe9' in file /usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py on line 262, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

More shown below those lines at https://pastebin.com/RCqFs78t.

If you take a look at locale.py file (https://pastebin.com/HfTUtqWb) you'll notice a lot of strange characters around line 263

I tried setting locale to en_US.UTF-8 to no avail. Any clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Quick workaround would be to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of `/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py`. Python 2 uses ASCII encoding by default.

Comment: Tried that, same outcome. Thx